# OrCAD Schematics NC pins

Tags: schematics

[image]Hi

I was working on this FT232RL USB to Serial Converter Circuit and now, in a doubt one thing. I understand that NC pins in the schematics have a cross Sign on them,but i didn't get this Pin12 CBUS4. As seen, the rest of the other pins have a cross sign but not this one. Is it another way of representing NC pin or is it connect

Answer (score 1):

The "X" makes it visually clear that the pin is intentional left unconnected, any typically it conveys to the design rule checking not to flag the pin as an error or warning.

So, as shown, it will look the same on the netlist as the other NC pins but may cause errors or warnings when you run DRC.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 12 do not appear as NC.
Have you tried placing NC (cross symbol) over it. You should check the properties of the particular pin. there is provision to also hide the NC pins in Orcad. If the Pin is not connected anywhere, ignore. Some other program which reads your schematics may feel bad about it still and give you a warning/Error.

Answer (score 0):

If the pin was defined as Power then the no connect symbol will not work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of those pins are used to drive LEDs to show Rx and Tx status.  If you are connecting those, the x may be a moot question.